# why doesn't os.system() run when placed in a for loop?

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I had the following (pseudo-)code:

```
import os

for s in settings:
    job_file = open("new_file_s.sh", "w")
    job_file.write("stuff that depends on s")
    os.system(command_that_runs_file_s)
```

Unfortunately, what happens is that the file corresponding to `s = settings[0]` is not executed, but then `s = settings[1]` is executed. Apparently, `os.system()` does not like running files that were recently created using `open()`, especially in the same iteration of a for loop.

The fix for me was to make sure any file executed via `os.system()` was initialized in a prior iteration of the for loop:

```
import os

# Stagger so that writing happens before execution:
job_file = open("new_file_settings[0].sh", "w")
job_file.write("stuff that depends on settings[0]")

for j in range(1, len(settings)):
    job_file = open("new_file_settings[j].sh", "w")
    job_file.write("stuff that depends on settings[j]")

    # Apparently, running a file in the same iteration of a for loop is taboo, so here we make sure that the file being run was created in a previous iteration:
    os.system(command_that_runs_file_settings[j-1])
```

This is obviously ridiculous and clumsy, so what do I do to fix this issue? (btw, the EXACT same behavior occurs with `subprocess.Popen()`).

Comment: I think the issue might be that you are not flushing/closing `job_file` before using `os.system()` to work on it. In such cases, you cannot gurantee the file would contain the correct entries you want. Try closing the file after you have worked on it, before trying to access it in `os.system()` .

Comment: `open("new_file_settings[j].sh", "w")`: you're opening a file called literally new_file_settings[j].sh, drop the quotes...

Comment: The title of this question is utterly misleading about what the problem is (it's not that the script *doesn't run*, but that it *can't see file contents*).

Comment: How would I know that? If I knew what was causing the problem then I wouldn't be asking this question. I spent hours testing and debugging and this was the best conclusion I could come to. What is a Q & A site good for if it is just people laughing at how the questioner doesn't know something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the issue with that code:

```
import os

for s in settings:
    job_file = open("new_file_s.sh", "w")
    job_file.write("stuff that depends on s")
    os.system(command_that_runs_file_s)
```

is that you're *not* closing `job_file`, so file is still open (and not flushed) when you run the system call.

Do `job_file.close()`, or better: use a context manager to ensure that the file is closed.

```
import os

for s in settings:
    with open("new_file_s.sh", "w") as job_file:
       job_file.write("stuff that depends on s")
    os.system(command_that_runs_file_s)
```